# Sabatier reaction oxygen to methane ratio for Mars ascent propellant

Tags: mars, chemistry, isru

The Sabatier reaction is as follows:

$$\mathrm{CO_2 + 4\: H_2 \rightarrow CH_4 + 2\: H_2O}.$$

If water is electrolysed

$$\mathrm{2\:H_2O \rightarrow 2\: H_2 + O_2}$$

the global reaction becomes

$$ \mathrm{CO_2 + 2\:H_2 \rightarrow CH_4 + O_2}.$$

Now, this gives an oxygen to methane ratio of 1:1 but both [this site](https://marspedia.org/Sabatier/Water_Electrolysis_Process) and [this article](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/6.2017-0423) state that the ratio is 4:1. Can someone explain what's missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a 4:1 ratio by mass. One molecule of methane masses 16 daltons, whereas one of dioxygen ($O_2$) masses 32, so two molecules of oxygen massed four times as as much as one of methane.

Comment: Thank you both @leftaroundabout and Steve Linton, I got it now. That being said, I'd need to "accept" both answers the way the information is split. Would you mind "joining" your answers together so that I can accept it please?

Comment: @leftaroundabout fine by me. Happy for you to update your answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: @SteveLinton just accept this answer, I think it is probably the real reason. Atom-counts aren't really relevant for rocket launches, mass ratio is. I'll leave my answer in place anyway as the explanation for the 2:1 molecule ratio.

Comment: But there's 1 molecule of each of methane & oxygen on the RHS of that last reaction. OTOH, to fully burn 1 molecule of methane requires 2 molecules of oxygen, producing 1 molecule of carbon dioxide & 2 molecules of water.

Answer (score 6):

In practice, what you do is actually you *start out* with water to generate the $\mathrm{H_2}$, rather than just electrolysing the water that comes out of the Sabatier reaction. (Well, you'd probably do that too: you feed it back into the start.) I.e. the overall reaction is
$$ \mathrm{CO_2 + 2\:H_2O \to CH_4 + 2\:O_2} $$

That still gives only a 2:1 ratio of $\mathrm{O_2}$ to $\mathrm{CH_4}$. What the article means by “ratio of 4:1 of oxygen to methane” must therefore be the ratio of oxygen atoms to carbon atoms.