# Could it be more cost-effective to refuel with on the lunar south pole produced methalox instead of refueling methalox in LEO, on the way to Mars?

Tags: the-moon, low-earth-orbit, isru, refueling, methalox

In the article [Prominent volcanic source of volatiles in the south polar region of the Moon](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0273117721007006#b0406) it is calculated that 8 x 10<sup>9</sup> kg $CO_2$ has been vented billions of years ago by pyroclastic events in the Schrodinger basin to a 1400 km² area within 5⁰ of the lunar south pole, together with 1.4 times more water in a much wider area of 20,000 km².

So theoretically the [Sabatier/Water Electrolysis Process](https://marspedia.org/Sabatier/Water_Electrolysis_Process) (link from [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/44327/sabatier-reaction-oxygen-to-methane-ratio-for-mars-ascant-propellant)) could be applied in this region with the water and carbon dioxide mined  to produce methane and oxygen.([methalox](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/methalox))
From the [Marspedia article](https://marspedia.org/Sabatier/Water_Electrolysis_Process): "Elon Musk of Spacex recently tweeted that they would start producing methane on Earth using the Sabatier process for their Starship launches."

On the other hand, [this article](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-how-to-refuel-starships-in-space/) states that refueling a Starship in LEO "-should be surprisingly efficient, with perhaps 80% or more of the propellant launched remaining usable by the end of the process.", with [Settled Cryogenic Propellant Transfer](https://ulalaunch.com/docs/default-source/extended-duration/settled-cryogenic-propellant-transfer-2006-4436.pdf).

**Question:** If it appears that producing LOX/Liquid hydrogen on the lunar south pole is economic and there's sufficient $CO_2$ there, then can it be inferred what the most cost-effective way to travel to Mars is: refueling with methalox from Earth in LEO or any other alternative way of (also) refueling with on the lunar south pole produced methalox ?

Comment: Which lunar refueling option are you considering, landing on the Moon or orbiting the Moon & having lunar methalox sent into orbit to a refueling "station"?

Comment: @Fred Good comment, any other alternative way can be considered, it made me think of the Lunar Gateway too. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Gateway . I adjusted the question somewhat.

Comment: Have to consider storage as well. I’m assuming the most cost effective storage will be in permanent shade on the moon, which should not be hard to find at the lunar South Pole. Storage in orbit will add complexity and cost. So make it in the sun (unless it’s nuclear powered), store it in the shade, where it might not require much power or even insulation, and transfer it to orbit at the right time (but that adds mission risk).

Comment: The first approximation answer should look specifically at a mission. Let's say you are going to Mars.  First question:  How much more delta-V do you need to first go to the Moon then to proceed to Mars, vs going direct from Earth orbit?  That will set an upper bound for how much it can cost for lunar fuel before it's not economical.  If that first aproximation shows it could be cheaper,  the next step would be to figure out the cost of shipping fuel up from the Moon into low lunar orbit.    That number is difficult, so do the simple calculation first in case you don't have to.

Comment: @DanHanson  That Marspedia article says the water electrolysis stage is by far the most energy intensive, so if it's economical to produce hydrogen/oxygen fuel on the Moon, we can suppose that applies to producing methalox there too, right ? Or could the production of hydrogen/oxygen there only be advantegeous because it's much harder to refuel hydrogen than methane in LEO ?